# Verilog: conditional branching

Tags: verilog

I want `iState` (the 2nd bar from the bottom) to be 0 on the rising edge of the clock (the bar at the very top) and when its current value is 1110 (provided that `iSkip` and `iRev` are both 0) or when 1010 (provided that `iSkip` is 1 and `iRev` are both 0). However, its going to 1111 instead. Does anyone know why this is happening and what I should do about it? Thanks.

[image]
Does anyone know what I should do about this? Thanks.

```
module CounterSkipReverse(iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev, oState);
   input iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev;
   //declare oState:
    output integer oState;
   //declare internal wires and reg types here:
    always @ (posedge iClk) begin
        if (iRst == 1)
            oState <= 0;
        else
            if (iSkip == 0 & iRev == 0) oState <= oState + 4'd1;
            else if (iSkip == 1 & iRev == 0) oState <= oState + 4'd5;
            else if (iSkip == 0 & iRev == 1) oState <= oState - 4'd1;
            else if (iSkip == 1 & iRev == 1) oState <= oState + 4'd9;
            if (oState < 0) oState <= oState + 4'd14;
            if (oState > 14) oState <= oState - 4'd14;
    end 
 
endmodule
 
module StateToCountSequence(iState, oV);
    //declare the input and output 
    input iState;
    output reg [3:0]oV;
  
    //declare any internal wire and reg types here.
    
    always @ (iState) begin
        case(iState)
            4'd0: oV = 4'd3;
            4'd1: oV = 4'd2;
            4'd2: oV = 4'd4;
            4'd3: oV = 4'd9;
            4'd4: oV = 4'd9;
            4'd5: oV = 4'd0;
            4'd6: oV = 4'd7;
            4'd7: oV = 4'd1;
            4'd8: oV = 4'd1;
            4'd9: oV = 4'd5;
            4'd10: oV = 4'd1;
            4'd11: oV = 4'd7;
            4'd12: oV = 4'd0;
            4'd13: oV = 4'd8;
            4'd14: oV = 4'd9;
        endcase
    end
  
    //Have you checked for inferred latches in this module?
endmodule 

module CompleteCounter(iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev, oV, oState);
    input iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev;
    output [3:0] oV;
    //declare oState next line
    output [3:0]oState;
    
    CounterSkipReverse cntr(.iClk(iClk), .iRst(iRst), .iSkip(iSkip), .iRev(iRev), .oState(oState));
    StateToCountSequence statemap(.iState(oState), .oV(oV));
endmodule

`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module AssignmentTestBench;
 
   //declare internal signals and instantiate module CompleteCounter.
    reg iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev;
    wire [3:0]oState;
    wire [3:0]oV;
    
    initial begin
        iClk = 1'b1;
        iRst = 0;
        iSkip = 0;
        iRev = 0;
    end
    
    CompleteCounter counter(iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev, oV, oState);
    
   //generate test sequences for all state transitions
    always begin
        #5 iClk = ~iClk;  //period 10 ns for clock
    end
    
    always begin  // control w input and reset
        #1;
        
        // iSkip = 0, iRev = 0
        #10 iRst = 1'b1;
        #10 iRst = 1'b0;
        #300;  // 30 clock cycles
        
        // iSkip = 1, iRev = 0
        #10 iRst = 1'b1;
        #10 iRst = 1'b0;
            iSkip = 1'b1;
        #80;
        
        // iSkip = 1, iRev = 1
        #10 iRst = 1'b1;
        #10 iRst = 1'b0;
            iRev = 1'b1;
        #40;
        
        // iSkip = 0, iRev = 1
        #10 iRst = 1'b1;
        #10 iRst = 1'b0;
            iSkip = 1'b0;
        #150;

        $display("Finished test");
        $finish;  // remove for modelsim
        $stop;
    end
  
endmodule
```

Comment: *provided that iSkip is 1 and iRev are both 0*? what are the values exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The way the `<=` work is to assign the value to the *oState* later, after the block is done. So, in the following while *oState* is scheduled to be 15, the *if* statement still sees it as `14`.

```
    oState <= oState + 1;
    ...
    if (oState > 14) ...
```

As minimum, you need `if(oState >= 14)`;

also, in the following statement

```
            if (oState > 14) oState <= oState - 4'd14;
```

if *oState* is really bigger than 14, i.e. 15, then `15 - 14 = 1`;

you probably need

```
            if (oState > 14) oState <= 0;
```

You need to figure out the other side of the expression as well. The problem is that `if (oState <= 0)` will give you a trouble in combination with `ostate <= 0`. You probably need something like the following there: `if (iSkip == 0 && iRev == 1 && oState <= 0)`

*A few more issues:*

BT*oState* is `integer` in *CounterSkipReverse* which is 32 bit wide signed. *istate* on the other hand is a `one-bit wide` input in *StateToCountSequence*. **You need to make all of them of the same width.** Your case statement will not work with 1-bit iState.

In addition, do not use singel `&` in conditional statements. use `&&. Though it does not matter in your case, it really matters in my suggestion which i provided above.

Do not use `always @(iState)`, use `always @*`.